# Why i dont have shipping method from admin, if they are have on my shopping cart

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods

I create shipping method by code, use https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/magento-2-create-shipping-method/

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you set the same address in admin as well, which you have used for shopping cart?

Comment: @TarunBhalodia yes